# how to verify that OS packages are removed or not installed in ansible

Tags: ansible, yum

So I am writing an ansible playbook which uninstalls some OS packages (in this case, all RedHat ABRT packages) and then checks if they were uninstalled. Uninstallation is not the problem (it works fine), but I need to verify if the packages were really uninstalled and then do some other stuff depending on that.

This is on RedHat 6.9 machine, and I am using Ansible 2.6.

```
  - name: list installed ABRT packages
    yum:
      list: abrt*
    register: abrt_packages
    when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
  - name: get package info
    set_fact:
      packages_installed: "{{abrt_packages|json_query(jsonquery)}}"
    vars:
      jsonquery: "results[?yumstate=='installed']"
  - debug:
      var: packages_installed
```

When running the ansible code above, I get no output - meaning, there are no packages with "yumstate": "installed" (despite the fact that they are actually installed):

```
user1@server1: [~]$ rpm -qa | grep abrt
abrt-python-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64
abrt-cli-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64
abrt-libs-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64
abrt-addon-python-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64
abrt-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64
abrt-tui-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64
```

Yum also shows them as installed.
If I modify the jsonquery to:

```
jsonquery: "results"
```

then I get this:

```
ok: [server1] => {
    "packages_installed": [
        {
            "arch": "x86_64", 
            "envra": "0:abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64", 
            "epoch": "0", 
            "name": "abrt-addon-ccpp", 
            "release": "43.el6", 
            "repo": "Repo1yum", 
            "version": "2.0.8", 
            "yumstate": "available"
        }, 
        {
            "arch": "x86_64", 
            "envra": "0:abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.8-43.el6.x86_64", 
            "epoch": "0", 
            "name": "abrt-addon-kerneloops", 
            "release": "43.el6", 
            "repo": "Repo1yum", 
            "version": "2.0.8", 
            "yumstate": "available"
        }, 
etc.
```

So, despite the fact that the ABRT packages are actually installed, their "yumstate" is "available" (instead of "installed"). Is this a bug in Ansible yum module or I am doing something wrong? How should I check if the ABRT packages (or any other package) are installed or not?

Answer (score 1):

Neither *list* nor *name* parameter of [yum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html) says that wildcards can be used. Quoting description of parameter list:

> Package name to run the equivalent of `yum list package` against. In addition to listing packages, use can also list the following: installed, updates, available and repos.

To list *installed* packages use

```
jsonquery: "results.packages_installed[?yumstate=='installed'].name"
```

Packages in the data *results.packages_installed* at *server1*, you posted, are **available**. Then

```
- set_fact:
    packages_available: "{{ abrt_packages|json_query(jsonquery) }}"
  vars:
    jsonquery: "results.packages_installed[?yumstate=='available'].name"
- debug:
    var: packages_available
```

gives (abridged):

```
"packages_available": [
    "abrt-addon-ccpp", 
    "abrt-addon-kerneloops"
]
```

Comment: Thank you @vladimir-botka, but it still does not work for me; I tried both of your examples on two different servers  (first server has the packages installed, and I uninstalled them manually on the 2nd server before testing). In all cases I got no output for "packages_installed" and "packages_available": `ok: [server1] => {
    "packages_installed": "" }` Since the "yumstate" is "available" on both servers, it is odd that the second code example did not show anything.

Comment: Thanks, with "list: installed" and removing the wildcard for yum _list_ parameter as you mentioned, I get back the list of all installed packages (yumstate=installed). 
Now I need to tell the jsonquery to filter for abrt* packages, which, judging by the jsonquery syntax, could be tricky...

Comment: [Keep it Simple, Stupid](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/kiss-keep-it-simple-stupid-a-design-principle) and use [select](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#select) "installed_packages|select('match', 'abrt*')|list"

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get it to work with the select statement you mentioned, apparently this syntax needs jinja 2.7 (I have 2.2, upgrades are not foreseen for a while). Anyway, this additional check for installed packages might actually not be needed, as Ansible should report back in case there were problems when uninstalling the packages with yum. Tested the playbook without this task and it works fine; thanks anyway for the help and suggestions!